# Correct way to use actions with ember-bootstrap

Tags: ember.js, ember-bootstrap

Created a new ember octane app (3.15) and using ember-bootstrap with it. I am using a modal like so

```
<BsModalSimple
  @open={{true}}
  @title="Create new podcast"
  @closeTitle="Cancel"
  @submitTitle="Create"
  @size="lg"
  @closeButton={{false}}
  @fade={{false}}
  @backdrop={{true}}
  @backdropClose={{false}}
  @renderInPlace={{false}}
  @onHidden={{action 'closeModal'}}
  @position="center">
</BsModalSimple>
```

This works but I get an error which says

> Do not use `action` as {{action ...}}. Instead, use the `on` modifier
>   and `fn` helper.

What's the right way to use an action in this scenario? I've tried this but it didn't work

```
{{on 'hidden' this.closeModal}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In classic Ember model (pre-octane), the `{{action}}` helper was used to bind the proper `this` context to the action/method that is being passed as a closure action. So, when the closure action is called inside any class, the action will have the caller's `this` context not the callee.

To be more predictable and explicit, this context binding was moved as a decorator, [@action](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0408-decorators.md#actions) which should be used to decorate your `closeModal` method instead of using the `{{action}}` helper in the template. So, your code can be:

```html
<!-- application.hbs -->

<BsModalSimple
  @open={{true}}
  @title="Create new podcast"
  @closeTitle="Cancel"
  @submitTitle="Create"
  @size="lg"
  @closeButton={{false}}
  @fade={{false}}
  @backdrop={{true}}
  @backdropClose={{false}}
  @renderInPlace={{false}}
  @onHidden={{this.closeModal}}
  @position="center">
</BsModalSimple>
```

```js
// controllers/application.js

import Controller from "@ember/controller";
import { action } from "@ember/object";

export default class ApplicationController extends Controller {
  @action
  closeModal() {
    // your implementation
  }
}
```

Please note that the error was thrown by the [linter](https://github.com/ember-template-lint/ember-template-lint/blob/master/docs/rule/no-action-modifiers.md) (ember-template-lint) and the error message can be more explicit to use the @action decorator.